# Ajax/PHP value not incrementing more than once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on developing a very simple voting system and as a proof of concept I have a div with a php defined variable that is supposed to be incremented by 1 when the button is clicked.  What I have so far is working, but only once... Why does the `votes` value not continue to go up when the button is clicked?

Here's my code so far:

**Voting page:**

```
<?php $votes = 0 ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function() 
    {
        var votes = document.getElementById("votes").innerHTML;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: votes,
            success: function(votes)
            {
                document.getElementById("votes").innerHTML = votes; 
            }                 
            });
    })
}); 
</script>
<div id="votes"><?= $votes ?></div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="vote!"/>
```

**ajax.php:**

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["votes"] + 1;            
?>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ajax request in developer tools? Is `votes` sent to the PHP script correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting here, you're not storing the value in any sort of temporary / permanent storage... Either use a session or increment the value in your javascript

Comment: Yes, it seems to be sent correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your server script you're trying to access a specific POST parameter - named `votes`. But in your client-side script you send to server just a string (value of `votes`), without marking it whatsoever.

Change `data: votes` line to `data: {votes: votes}` or similar, first; correct your script so that `$_POST['votes']` is not set, it signals an error:

```
if (! isset($_POST['votes'])) {
   throw new Exception('No value for votes'); 
}
echo $_POST['votes'] + 1;
```

Note that you would have noticed this even without almighty SO. ) See, the original code should've been triggering E_NOTICE (as `$_POST['votes']` wasn't defined), if only `error_reporting` level hadn't been set too high. Remember, in development `error_reporting(-1)` line is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your variable into some more permanent location. So far, it is lost every time your script terminates (every page load). Store it in $_SESSION and you'll be good to go. Note that you need to call session_start() for [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to work.